# Limit of ratio of $2$ functions

Tags: calculus, limits, algorithms, asymptotics, ratio

I need some help with my homework.
How do I prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n})}{4^\sqrt{n}} =0\:?$$

I need to compare the growth rate of these functions and I know that $4^\sqrt{n}$ grows faster and thats why the limit should be $0$.

But how do I solve this? What steps should I show that lead this equation to being $0$?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Observe that $n^3\le4^{\sqrt n}$ and from this it follows that
$$\frac{(\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n})}{4^\sqrt{n}} =\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}(n)4^\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{1}{\log_{2}(n)}.$$

If we let $n\to\infty$ we can see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log_{2}(n)}=0.$$

In conclusion:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\frac{(\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n})}{4^\sqrt{n}}}_{\text{non-negative}}\le0\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n})}{4^\sqrt{n}}}=0$$

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. But what in this argument would break if we replace the $4^{\sqrt{n}}$ by e.g. $n^2$? And surely we don't have $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^3 / \log n = 0$ right?

Comment: You can do this. But at the end you will have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(\frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n})}{4^\sqrt{n}}}\leq\infty,$$ which is obviously still correct but inconclusive.

Comment: What I mean is, if the original question was to find the limit of $(n^3 / \log n)/ n^2 \leq n^3 / \log n$, then going through the same steps you just did would give a limit of zero, while the actual limit is $\infty$ right?

Comment: (What you wrote now is another problem.) Step by step: $(n^3/\log n)/n^2\leq n^3/\log n$, this is correct. But I cannot see how the first limit is zero by my steps. The expression $n^3/\log n$ does not tend to zero either.

Comment: Thank you very very much! :)

Comment: @vitamind Hmm I guess I am somehow missing a step somewhere. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Slugger Suppose you have a non-negative limit you want to calculate. We'll call it $L$. Now you can find another limit, we'll call it $G$ that satisfies $L\leq G$. Indeed it is possibile that $G\to\infty$. But that does not necessarily mean  that $L\to\infty$ too. Also $G$ could be $5$, for example. Then we'd have $L\leq 5$, but we still don't know the exact value of $L$. Only if we find a $G$ that is equal to $0$ we can find the exact value of $L$ because we have $L\leq0\Rightarrow L=0$, since $L$ is non-negative.

Comment: Right, but the $G$ in this case is the limit of $n^3 /\log_2n$ right?

Comment: Oh yes I see. I forgot to cancel the $n^3$ too from my old answer. Thank you very much. Luckily this is not a big mistake since trivially $n^3\le 4^{\sqrt n}$, but still a mistake. I edited my answer. Now it's correct.

Comment: @vitamind  you answered a pretty poor question, essentially, a PSQ

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for pointing this out. I will delete it. Sorry cannot not delete an accepted answer. What should I do?